# Why does geofencingClient.addGeofences always return failure

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-geofence

I have a fragment and I am trying to create geofences around checkpoints. `GEOFENCE_RADIUS` is set to 50F. In `Log.i(TAG, "geofences: $geofences, request $geofencingRequest, intent: $geofencePendingIntent")`, I am getting not getting any null objects back so it seems to me that the geofences, request, and intent are getting initialized. What could be causing the failure in `geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, geofencePendingIntent)`?

```
private fun createGeofences(){
        val geofences = currTour.checkpoints!!.map {
            Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(it.name)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setCircularRegion(it.location.latitude, it.location.latitude, GEOFENCE_RADIUS)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
                .build()
        }

        val geofencingRequest = GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
            setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            addGeofences(geofences)
        }.build()

        val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
            val intent = Intent(context, GeofenceReceiver::class.java)
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "geofences: $geofences, request $geofencingRequest, intent: $geofencePendingIntent")

        val geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(activity!!)

        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, geofencePendingIntent).run {
            Log.i(TAG, "in addGeofences")
            addOnFailureListener {
                // display error
                Log.i(TAG, "failure") //always hits this line
            }
            addOnSuccessListener {
                // move on
                Log.i(TAG, "success listener")
                Toast.makeText(context, "SUCCESS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            }
        }

    }
```